# Has the Feynman-Kac formula been extended to the complex case?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, path-integral

Wikipedia writes that the Feynman-Kac formula "proves rigorously the real-valued case of Feynman's path integrals. The complex case, which occurs when a particle's spin is included, is still an open question" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman%E2%80%93Kac_formula). But the citation for this claim is from 1987. Is this question still open? If so, could anybody point me to examples of recent work on the topic?